# Is there any way for a C++ template function to take exactly N arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

What I mean is, for example, a constructor for a class like the following:

```
class vector<size_t N, typename FLOAT=double> {
    vector(FLOAT ...x) {} // I want exactly N arguments here
};
```

I hope it's clear that I do *not* want a variadic function, but a function that takes *exactly* N arguments, when N is known at compile-time. Thus, using the example above, `vector<3>(1.5, 2.5)` should produce a compile-time error, while `vector<2>(1.5, 2.5)` should compile and run.

Is this possible?

I was thinking that perhaps this could be done with parameter packs, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: @aschepler Well, that's a bummer. :( I misread that code.

Comment: So sizeof...(FLOAT) always equals N. Your template interface asks twice the same information. This is as odd as a template that would take two type arguments with the requirement that the two arguments are the same.

Comment: @Oliv: No, `FLOAT` is only supposed to be specified once (as either `float`, `double`, or `long double`), representing the type of the vector elements. So `vector<3, float> *v = new vector<3, float>(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With some indirection, you may do something like:

```
template <std::size_t, typename T> using alwaysT = T;

template <typename FLOAT, typename Seq> struct vector_impl;

template <typename FLOAT, std::size_t... Is>
struct vector_impl<FLOAT, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
     vector_impl(alwaysT<Is, FLOAT>... floats) { /*...*/}
};

template <std::size_t N, typename FLOAT>
using vector = vector_impl<FLOAT, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

Comment: That's slick. I was sure it would be necessary to SFINAE-restrict a general variadic constructor.

Comment: It took me a while of staring to figure out how that works. Thanks! I hope it works with standalone functions as well...

Comment: Actually, how *would* you do this with standalone functions? Since you can't forward declare a function without specifying arguments. Would you have to make it a static function of a dummy class?

Comment: Functor is indeed a good way,  call syntax would be `foo<2>{}(4.2f, 5.1f)`. Alternative would use SFINAE (or `static_assert`) with more regular syntax.

Comment: A functor is completely unnecessary, since a static member function does just as well. I ended up using your answer to create a static member function as a helper, and wrapped it with something similar to @ChrisKitching's suggestion (without a `static_assert` being necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way is just to use `static_assert`. Add pattern matching as appropriate:

```
template<int N, typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == N, "Incorrect number of arguments");
    // stuff
}
```

This will do most of the time, even allowing you to have a nice friendly custom error.

You can even go a bit crazy and use foldexprs to apply even more constraints on the arguments:

```
static_assert(((std::is_integral_v<Args>) && ...), "All arguments must be integers");
```

The value of this approach compared to SFINAE-based solutions is that you can get less insane compile errors.

If using C++20, you can use the new `requires` keyword to apply the same concept in a more powerful/friendly way.

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood the question. The OP does not wish to have to actually specify the type _N_ times.

Comment: Although, to be fair, thinking about it, if you let everything be deduced this may be a fair compromise

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Even if everything is deduced, this lets you provide a different type for each argument, which I don't want.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah it's definitely not strictly the answer. But I am trying to be charitable :)

Comment: There are still possibility to have also something like `static_assert(all_of_type<FLOAT, Args...>::value, "!");`.

Comment: You can add any pattern matching you require, or add further asserts. A series of static asserts like this with inferred types is probably easier to read in all but the most complex of cases than a complicated tangle of SFINAE magic.

Comment: That's pretty true tbf.

Comment: It's also worth noting the compile errors. With SFINAE solutions you'll get a huge resolution failure error, complete with template expansion backtraces and all sorts of madness. With this approach you get one of the helpfully-worded asserts _which you wrote_. I have been known to write functions like this just so I'm able to make a helpful custom compile error for common errors, instead of leaving it to the resolution failure error.