# Make generic Lambda with exactly N arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates

I want to dynamically create math expressions with lambdas, [as reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277794/evaluating-math-terms-as-nested-lambdas-instead-of-expression-tree).

```
using Func = std::function<double(double)>;

Func operator+(Func const& lhs, Func const& rhs){
    return [lhs, rhs](double x){
        return lhs(x) + rhs(x);
    };
}
```

My next goal is to generalize this.

[Thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48818570/5436259) I managed to implement a generic type with exactly n arguments. But I do not know - if at all possible -  how to specify the lambda arguments.

[check it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:29,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:29,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Cstd::size_t,+typename+T%3E+using+alwaysT+%3D+T%3B%0A%0A%09template+%3Ctypename+FLOAT,+typename+Seq%3E+struct+func_struct%3B%0A%0A%09template+%3Ctypename+FLOAT,+std::size_t...+Is%3E%0A%09struct+func_struct%3CFLOAT,+std::index_sequence%3CIs...%3E%3E+%7B%0A%09%09using+type+%3D+std::function%3Cdouble(alwaysT%3CIs,+FLOAT%3E...+floats)%3E%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09template+%3Cstd::size_t+N%3E%0A%09using+func_t+%3D+typename+func_struct%3Cdouble,+std::make_index_sequence%3CN%3E%3E::type%3B%0A%0A%09template+%3Cstd::size_t+N%3E%0A%09func_t%3CN%3E+operator%2B(func_t%3CN%3E+const%26+lhs,+func_t%3CN%3E+const%26+rhs)%7B%0A%09%09return+%5Blhs,+rhs%5D(alwaysT%3CN,+std::make_index_sequence%3CN%3E%3E+args...)%7B%0A%09%09%09lhs(args)+%2B+rhs(args)%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++func_t%3C1%3E+f1+%3D+%5B%5D(double+x)%7Breturn+x*2%3B%7D%3B%0A++++func_t%3C2%3E+f2+%3D+%5B%5D(double+x,+double+y)%7B+return+x*y%3B%7D%3B%0A%0A++++func_t%3C1%3E+f3+%3D+f1+%2B+f1%3B%0A%0A%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:37.885201283285824,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:arm1210,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%270%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-O2+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27ARM+gcc+12.1+(linux)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:0.9445064031844101,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g121,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:13.494218991053348,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+4.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+ARM+gcc+12.1+(linux)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.67607332247642,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <functional>

template <std::size_t, typename T> using alwaysT = T;

    template <typename FLOAT, typename Seq> struct func_struct;

    template <typename FLOAT, std::size_t... Is>
    struct func_struct<FLOAT, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
        using type = std::function<double(alwaysT<Is, FLOAT>... floats)>;
    };

    template <std::size_t N>
    using func_t = typename func_struct<double, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;

    template <std::size_t N>
    func_t<N> operator+(func_t<N> const& lhs, func_t<N> const& rhs){
        return [lhs, rhs](alwaysT<N, std::make_index_sequence<N>> args...){// how to do this?
            lhs(args) + rhs(args);
        };
    }

int main(){
    func_t<1> f1 = [](double x){return x*2;};
    func_t<2> f2 = [](double x, double y){ return x*y;};

    func_t<1> f3 = f1 + f1;


}
```

I'm also getting an error that the template argument `N` can not be deduced, in the last line.

Comment: easiest is to accept `auto&&...` and then do `static_assert()` on types and arg count. Note that it's an error to have a different number of arguments.

Comment: @lorro this should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: posted as such, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the standard allows you to manage argument count restriction like that, but you can definitely have an assert if the arg count is in mismatch. E.g.:

```
#include <functional>

template <std::size_t, typename T> using alwaysT = T;

    template <typename FLOAT, typename Seq> struct func_struct;

    template <typename FLOAT, std::size_t... Is>
    struct func_struct<FLOAT, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
        using type = std::function<double(alwaysT<Is, FLOAT>... floats)>;
    };

    template <std::size_t N>
    struct func_t : func_struct<double, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type {
        using Base = typename func_struct<double, std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
        using Base::Base;
    };

    template <std::size_t N>
    func_t<N> operator+(func_t<N> const& lhs, func_t<N> const& rhs){
        return [lhs, rhs](auto&&... args){
            return lhs(args...) + rhs(args...);
        };
    }

int main(){
    func_t<1> f1 = [](double x){return x*2;};
    func_t<2> f2 = [](double x, double y){ return x*y;};

    func_t<1> f3 = f1 + f1;
}
```

Note, I've changed the `template<size_t N> using func_t` to a `template<size_t N> struct func_t` so that matching on template argument is possible. `using` declarations are always replaced before matching and the compiler (as per current standard) is not expected to be able to deduce `N` from `<double, 0, 1, 2, ...>`.

Comment: This does not compile (also where does `T` come from?)

Comment: The problem is not with the lambda arg count. It's with that you expect `func_t<N>` to be matched on `N`. That won't happen as it's a template alias to a much more sophisticated type. Either you can have a `template<size_t N> struct func_t` for this to work, or (not recommended) you might call the `template operator+<N>()` manually

Comment: Added an explanation and full source.

Comment: Your explanations and answer are very much appreciated. Great insight!